# Error when restoring full system backup on a new Server (Bitnami Magento 2.2.1)

Tags: magento2, database, backup

I'm migrating a webshop to a new server, I was hoping it could be as simple as doing a full system backup on one server and a restore on the new server.

But after restoring the backup on the new server I cannot access the website anymore and when I run the `bnconfig --machine_hostname` command I get the following error output:

> BlocProblem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
>    Error running /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql --user=bn_magento --host=localhost --socket="/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock" --database=bitnami_magento -p**** <<"EOF"
>   UPDATE core_config_data SET value ='http://54.194.xx.xx/' WHERE core_config_data.path ='web/unsecure/base_url';
>   EOF: Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
>   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bn_magento'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   kquote

So this leads me to believe that the new server is having issues with some hardcoded passwords in config files that needs to be updated for the new database.

Does anyone know where I should look for these config files, or could the problem be something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was that I had to edit the /app/etc/env.php

In there, the MySQL credentials for the application can be found and in my case I had to change just the password string with the correct one